# moment.js giving a incorrect diff between

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have the following code:

```js
let moment = require('moment-timezone');
let now = moment().tz('America/Montevideo');
let limit_date = moment('2020-02-13 14:46:19', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
let diff = now.unix() - limit_date.unix();

console.log('now', now.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
console.log('limit_date', limit_date.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
console.log('diff', diff);
console.log('diff', now.diff(limit_date, 'seconds'));
```

When I run the code, I get the following console output:

```
now 13/02/2020 15:27:08
limit_date 13/02/2020 14:46:19
diff 6049
diff 6049
```

Since the correct difference should be 2449 seconds, what I`m doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

When I do

```js
let now = _moment(_moment().tz('America/Montevideo').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Then the difference in seconds is correct.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the timezone. I guess `now` and `limit_date` are in different timezones, so diff result seems to be inconsistent while it is not. You can check the timezones by logging the variables (with `console.log`)

Comment: `limit_date` has no timezone set, so it is taking ur browser default timezone and then when you difference it, it should the difference between ur browser default timezone with America/Montevideo

Comment: @prasanakannan I took a look on the docs but didnt found how to set the timezone without changing the date. I mean, when i try: moment('2020-02-13 14:46:19', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').tz('America/Montevideo') the original date (2020-02-13 14:46:19') is translated to the new timezone. Do you know how to do it in a elegant way?

Comment: @user3157543 I've post my answer. Kindly give it a try. I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `now` and `limit_date` are in different timezone. when you specify a time without any timezone it takes the browser default locale as timezone.

Use Timezone as third argument when you initialise it

```
 moment('2020-02-13 14:46:19', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', 'America/Montevideo');
```

```js
let moment = require('moment-timezone');
let now = moment().tz('America/Montevideo');
let limit_date = moment('2020-02-13 14:46:19', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', 'America/Montevideo');
let diff = now.unix() - limit_date.unix();
```

Comment: moment('2020-02-13 14:46:19', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss', 'America/Montevideo'); has the same effect as using  moment('2020-02-13 14:46:19', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').tz('America/Montevideo'); wich changes the date, giving me the wrong seconds difference.

Comment: Strange..!!
could you please try with this.

let now = moment().tz('America/Montevideo');
let limit_date = moment(moment('2020-02-13 14:46:19', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'), "America/Montevideo");
let diff = now.unix() - limit_date.unix();

Comment: This way works, but it doesnt look too elegant. I was able to achieve it doing let now = _moment(_moment().tz('America/Montevideo').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); but is also not elegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: "*browser default locale as timezone*" should be "*host timezone offset*". While locale and timezone offset may be loosely related, they are usually set separately and are not specific to, or necessarily anything to do with, each other or browser settings.